# Add a Loading indicator when calling to a Web Services - objective c

Tags: objective-c, web-services, uiactivityindicatorview

I am developing an iPhone app. One of its features is: I push a button, so it appears a tableView with data obtained from a database. This works properly.

The thing is that, sometimes, when I tap that button, the app freezes while a couple of seconds, so I would like to add a Loading Indicator or something like that, to show that you have to wait a little bit.

Well, I have implemented the loading indicator, and it works because I've checked it in other views. The problem is that when I tap the button, I add the subview, and I push the new viewController, where in its viewWillAppear, webService is called. So the app freezes, but does not show any Loading indicator. It freezes exactly, in a NSURLConnection when I send a Request to the Web Service, but, I dont know why, subView is not added. If I do not remove the subview, when I get back to this view from the tableView, loading indicator is showed.

So I have no idea how to solve this problem.

If you could help me, it would be great.

I attach some pieces of my code

```
    - (IBAction)menuButtonPressed:(id)sender{

   LoadingIndicator *load = [[LoadingIndicator alloc] init];
[load addLoadingView:self.view];

NSString *boton = [sender currentTitle];

if ([boton isEqualToString:@"Lugares"]){

    CategoriesViewController *catController = [[CategoriesViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CategoriesViewController" bundle:nil];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:catController animated:YES];
    [catController release];

 }   
}
```

LoadingIndicator, is a class where I make the subview with the Indicator.

Answer (score 2):

You are going to want add a thread:

```
//add your loading view
dispatch_async( dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    // make your web service call here

    dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // process results from web service call
        // remove loading view
    });
});
```